# Why can't I re-initialize an Array in a function?

Tags: c#, arrays, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

In C#, arrays are passed to functions by reference, which means that this code :

```
static void FillArray(int[] A) {
     for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++) {
          A[i] = -1;
     }
}

static void Main(string[] args) {
    int[] A = new int[10];

    FillArray(A);

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", A));
}
```

will produce    `-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1`
which is the expected answer. But if I re-initialize the array like this:

```
static void FillArray(int[] A) {
    A = new int[2*A.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++) {
        A[i] = -1;
    }
}
```

The output will be `0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0` !!

Shouldn't `A` change since it's passed as a reference to the function ?

Comment: `A` is a reference object.  But you are passing that reference object by value. @JonSkeet has [a good article](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html) on this

Comment: `int[]` is a reference type, but `A` is not passed by reference. They are 2 different terms that many people mix up. The term "reference type" is about types. The term "pass-by-reference" is about variables. You can pass `A` by reference by changing the method to: `FillArray(ref int[] A)`.

Comment: Good time to start to read some c# documents.....

Answer (score 2):

when FillArray starts running it has a variable called A that points to the array you setup in main (coincidentally called A)

In your second case you change the local A to point to a different array. So any changes you make are not seen by the calling code - there is no relationship between the 2 A variables

Really this is not 'by reference' parameter passing since changing the passed value (A) is not reflected in the callers space. You are getting a 'pointer' by value (In quotes since c# will argue its not a pointer since managed code doesn't have pointers)

Answer (score 1):

You can alter the values that are contained in the array, `A` but you can't alter the `A`. When you call a method, you pass actually copies (by default) of the argument's values. If you want to alter `A` you have to pass it by reference, using the `ref` keyword:

```
static void FillArray(ref int[] A) {
    A = new int[2*A.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++) {
        A[i] = -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Internally, the address of the array is what is being passed. By modifying the items in that array, the caller will see those changes. But if you assign the array to a new array, it no longer points to the caller's array. And the caller will not see any changes to that array.

So, while the array is passed by reference, the reference itself is passed by value unless you use the `ref` keyword.